# Unable to invoke annotation processor - while deploying in Weblogic 12.2.1.2.0

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic8.x

I am in process of migrating a java project from weblogic 8.1 to weblogic 12c.

As per oracle document i  have converted below things.

```
 1. Servicegen converted to jwsc task
 2. deployment descriptor has been modified
 3. Below annotations added in service implementation file

  @WebService
  @SoapBinding
  @SoapMessageHandler
```

After all above changes did generate war file and deployed in weblogic 12c server which throws error like below

```
Unable to invoke annotation processor

<BEA-160228> App merge failed your application
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: unable to invoke annotation processor
```

Code :

```
package com.tutorialspoint.stateless;

import com.tutorialspoint.entity.Book;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName="LibraryService")
public class LibraryPersistentBean implements LibraryPersistentBeanRemote {
    
   public LibraryPersistentBean() {
   }

   @PersistenceContext(unitName="EjbComponentPU")
   private EntityManager entityManager;         

   public void addBook(Book book) {
      entityManager.persist(book);
   }    
   
   @WebMethod(operationName="getBooks")
   public List <Book> getBooks() {
      return entityManager.createQuery("From Book").getResultList();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code for testing ?

Comment: @AnishB. Added the sample code.

Comment: @learner at which line you are getting the exception.

Comment: @WebService(serviceName="LibraryService")

Comment: @AnishB. Any suggestion for this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846539/how-to-acheive-servicegen-behavior-in-jwsc-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Servlet mapping caused an issue in **webservice.xml** while migration.

```
<servlet-link></servlet-link>
```

Comment: could you or anyone provide an example of the webservice.xml? I don't have it, maybe the web.xml?