# How to achieve servicegen behavior in jwsc task?

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws, weblogic12c, jax-ws-customization

Migrating a java soap web service from 11g to 12c which has few operations.

Used jwsc task to generate WSDL which generates all the input elements starting with uppercase and "ArrayOf" elements not coming along with wsdl.

This behavior was good in 11g where wsdl generation happens through servicegen task, In 12c servicegen not available.

Any suggestion to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

servicegen is from WLS 8.1 (this version had a proprietary webservices jax-rpc runtime). That runtime was removed in 12c.

You are migrating JAX-RPC to JAX-WS, however you have an important constraint:

*> - SOAP Arrays are not supported by JAX-WS; they are available in JAX-RPC*

Further details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24497/upgrade_ws.htm#WLUPG334